# How do I click Alertify dialog button using selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I have below code which works fine and clicks on "OK" button properly if I have only one alertify dialog with "OK" text,

```
def click_element(self, element):
    element.click()

def find_by_xpath(self, xpath):
    return driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)

self.click_element(self.find_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'OK')]"))
```

But If I have more than one alertify dialog in the page with same "OK" button then it fails to click on alertify dialog which is active on screen, 
the issue here I think is the hidden alertify dialog which also has "OK" button. I googled but I did not find a way to write xpath for this issue.

Here one alertify dialog is hidden and one alertify dialog is on screen which I want to click(with "OK" button)

I've noticed that the alertify dialog which is currently open do not have "ajs-out ajs-hidden" classes in it (you can refer screenshot attached).

[image]

Ref: [Alertify Dialog example](http://alertifyjs.com/factory.html) (See the "Default usage" example code)

Comment: Maybe the xpath you have is not correct. Try the xpath `'//div[@class='ajs-primary']/button'`

Comment: updated the screenshot for more clarity of issue

Comment: While the image of the HTML in this case is somewhat helpful because you've labeled it, in general posting the HTML as text is much more useful because it allows readers to grab the text and use it to try to solve your problem. In my case, I had to convert parts of the image to text to test my XPath which is cumbersome.

Comment: Sorry @JeffC,I'll keep that mind next time when I post any question... [that was one of the reason I gave example link of alertify dialog :-) , which has same html/css code which I have posted here in screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below fixed my issue,

Correct xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'alertify') and not(contains(@class, 'ajs-hidden'))]//button[.='OK']")
```

Thanks to **JeffC** for showing me how exclude(negate the condition) classs :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clarification... it all makes more sense now. :)

So you basically have two (or more) OK buttons, only one of which is visible. There are a few ways you can do this:

1. Locate all buttons that contain OK, loop through them to find the one that is visible, and click on it.
2. Craft an XPath that looks for a button that contains OK that isn't a descendant of a `DIV` that contains the class `ajs-hidden` and click on it.

I'm going to do #2.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[not(@class='ajs-hidden')]//button[.='OK']").click()
```

A sidenote/suggestion... don't wrap basic Selenium methods in a wrapper function as you've done with `click_element()` and `find_by_xpath()`. They really don't achieve anything and you've created a proprietary API for Selenium that other people that read your code will have to learn. Keep it simple. The one liner above should do exactly what you need and is understandable to anyone that knows Selenium and python.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the screenshot for more clarity of issue

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[not(@class='ajs-hidden')]//button[.='OK']").click() did not worked :(

Comment: It works with the HTML you supplied. Post a link to the page?

Comment: If you found this (or any) answer helpful, please upvote it. If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!